# Using ng-repeat or ngFor to display each object in a JSON object as individual list items

Tags: json, angular, typescript, frontend, angular6

I recieve an object that looks like this: 
[image]

I'm trying to use ng-repeat to display the "Message", "Priority" and "DateTime" properties of each object as li items in a ul.

I've tried a couple of approaches including ng-repeat and ngFor, where all have been wrapped in divs like the first option:

1. This seems like the proper way to do it, but returns exactly nothing:

   `<div style="background: red;">
     <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="Notification in allNotifications">{{Notification}}</li>
     </ul>
   </div>`
2. This option returns the specific object as expected:

   `<li style="border-radius: 3px" 
   [ngStyle]="{'color' : alertText}" >
   Notification: {{ allNotifications.Notifications['0'].Message['0'] }}
   </li>`
3. Doesnt compile:

   `<li style="border-radius: 3px" 
   [ngStyle]="{'color' : alertText}" 
   [ngFor]="let subItem of allNotifications.Notifications['0'].Message['0']">
   Notification: {{ subItem }}
   </li>`

My TS looks like this:

```
export class EventLogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _dashdata: DashdataService) { }

  NotificationName: string;
  alertText: string;
  allNotifications: JSON;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.NotificationName = 'NoNameAvailable';
    this.alertText = 'Black'; //TODO: set color according to threatlevel

    setInterval(() => {
      this._dashdata.getAllNotifications()
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.allNotifications = res['notificationdata'];
          console.log(this.allNotifications);
        });
    }, 5000); // Data Update interval in MS
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the output of console.log(this.allNotifications);?

Comment: The object in the image

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngforof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using angular you should forget ng-repeat that is apart of AngularJS (version <= 1.6)

I think you have a double problem, the first one, as said, is ng-repeat, the second one is that you are not well targeting your data.

Try this

template

```
<div style="background: red;">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let not of allNotifications.Notification">{{not}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`ng-repeat` is directive of framework AngularJS.

You are using Angular so in your case you should use `ngFor`:

```
<div style="background: red;"> 
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let notification of allNotifications">  
      {{notification}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```